# Program Dev C++ [Error] id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

I have this error and I tried everything to get rid of it and compile but I didn't succeed, I searched on this same web about this errors but that didn't worked for me, I have restarted my pc and also change the name of the file but I got nothing, also, I dont know if it has to be a problem with the *const* because before this error I got C:\Users\Brand\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSqL8DC.o   yhh.cpp:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `promedio(int const*, int)' this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ESTUDIANTES 3
#define EXAMENES 4

int minimo( const int calificaciones[][ EXAMENES ], int alumnos, int examenes );
int maximo( const int calificaciones[][ EXAMENES ], int alumnos, int examenes );
double promedio( const int estableceCalif[], int examenes );
void despliegaArreglo( const int calificaciones[][ EXAMENES ], int alumnos, int examenes );

int main()
{
   int estudiante; 

 const int calificacionesEstudiantes[ ESTUDIANTES ][ EXAMENES ] ={ { 77, 68, 86, 73 }, { 96, 87, 89, 78 }, { 70, 90, 86, 81 } };

printf( "El arreglo es:\n" );
despliegaArreglo( calificacionesEstudiantes, ESTUDIANTES, EXAMENES );

printf( "\n\nCalificacion mas baja: %d\nCalificacion mas alta: %d\n",
minimo( calificacionesEstudiantes, ESTUDIANTES, EXAMENES ),
maximo( calificacionesEstudiantes, ESTUDIANTES, EXAMENES ) );


for ( estudiante = 0; estudiante < ESTUDIANTES; estudiante++ ) {
printf( "El promedio de calificacion del estudiante %d es %.2f\n", estudiante, promedio( calificacionesEstudiantes[ estudiante ], EXAMENES ) );
 }

 return 0;

 }

 int minimo( const int calificaciones[][ EXAMENES ], int alumnos, int
examenes )
 {
    int i;
    int j; 
    int califBaja = 100; 

 for ( i = 0; i < alumnos; i++ ) {

 for ( j = 0; j < examenes; j++ ) {

 if ( calificaciones[ i ][ j ] < califBaja ) {califBaja = calificaciones[ i ][ j ];
 } 
 } 
 } 
 return califBaja; 
 } 
 int maximo( const int calificaciones[][ EXAMENES ], int alumnos, int
examenes )
 {
 int i;
 int j; 
 int califAlta = 0; 


 for ( i = 0; i < alumnos; i++ ) {


 for ( j = 0; j < examenes; j++ ) {

 if ( calificaciones[ i ][ j ] > califAlta ) { califAlta = calificaciones[ i ][ j ];
 }
 } 
 }

 return califAlta;
 }
 void despliegaArreglo( const int calificaciones[][ EXAMENES ], int alumnos, int examenes )
 {
 int i; 
 int j; 

 printf( " [0] [1] [2] [3]" );
 for ( i = 0; i < alumnos; i++ ) {


 printf( "\ncalificacionesEstudiantes[%d]", i );


 for ( j = 0; j < examenes; j++ ) {
 printf( "%-5d", calificaciones[ i ][ j ] );
 } 
 } 
 }
```

Comment: That error is probaby about `ld` not `id`, which may be why your search didn't turn up anything.  Anyway, you've declared a function named `promedio` and you're calling it, but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `despliegaArreglo`, `minimo`, `maximo`, and `promedio`, but only provide implementations for the first three.

If you provide an implementation for `promedio` like so, it will compile:

```
double promedio( const int estableceCalif[], int examenes )
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

Of course, this probably isn't what you want `promedio` to do.  Maybe you want:

```
double promedio( const int estableceCalif[], int examenes )
{
    if (examenes ==0) return 0.0;
    double average = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<examenes; ++i)
      average += estableceCalif[i];
    average /= examenes;
    return average;
}
```

Also, I should point out that your code compiles as `C`, and stuff like this is significantly easier in `C++` which is what you tagged.  For example, I can create a list of students and their exam scores, and calculate an average for each one as easy as:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
using std::vector;

int main()
{
  vector<int> student1 = { 56, 90, 72 };
  vector<int> student2 = { 90, 98 };
  vector < vector<int> > students = { student1, student2 };
  for (auto &curStudent : students)
    double average = std::accumulate(curStudent.begin(), curStudent.end(), 0.0) / curStudent.size();
}
```

Comment: That actually solved the problem, I don't really know what you did but thank you so much.

Comment: @JohanMorales - See update to answer.  Hopefully it is a good thing that you are learning `C` and not `C++`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, probably you have  been using any reserved word 
and you have not declared the standard library for this reserved word.